# Integrate Google Colab GPUs with docker

Tags: python, docker, gpu, google-colaboratory

I am trying to build a Reinforcement Learning tool, but I have no access to a GPU nor can I afford it. Due to this, I was thinking on using the GPU resources provided freely, for example, by Google Colab. Nevertheless, my project cannot be executed as a python notebook, because it is a very big project consisting on several dependencies and modules. Because of that, I'd like to know if there is any way to integrate Google Colab with docker so that a docker image that uses the GPUs form Google Colab can be built in order to use that GPU when training my model. Any other way of integrating free GPUs in my docker container will be valid as well.